# Is there some way to search filter on button click without using .includes or indexOf(element) functions?

Tags: javascript, string, search

I want to display searched games. When I type "call of " and click search button I want element with image title 'Call Of Duty : 5 " to only be displayed. I tried this but its returning every game so I want to know if there is some way to compare two strings

```
   const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

if (radioName.checked) {
    document.querySelectorAll('img')
        .forEach(img => {
            if (lower(img.title).includes(lower(text))) {
                img.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = '';
            }
            else {
                img.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
}
```

This is returning every game because they all have common letters with input string. Here is photo example:
[image]

Comment: As far as I know, Array.indexOf() and Array.includes() only match exactly. You may have to look into a RegEx solution.

Comment: Are you sure you need that many `parentElement`s? What happens when you remove 1?

Comment: I think you want `toLowerCase` – `img.title.toLowerCase()`

Comment: @imvain2 Those images are contained inside a element which is inside td element which is inside tr element so I am removing tr element if input value does not match img title value

Comment: You're looking for `some` or `findIndex`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which browsers you are focusing on, you can use a CSS attribute selector `*` with the `i` flag. https://caniuse.com/css-case-insensitive

```js
imgs = document.querySelectorAll('[title*="Call Of Duty" i]');

imgs.forEach(function(img){
    img.style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
img{display:none}
```

```html
<img title="Call Of duty" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500/500">
```